# The purpose of LU Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I was curious if anyone could help me understand why an LU decomposition is useful from a theoretical or computational standpoint. It seems to me that it is just a way to teach students the basics of factorizing a matrix. If it is useful, What utility does the lower triangular half possess that one does not get from merely doing Elimination and reducing to upper triangular form?

Thanks!

Comment: From a computational standpoint, it can be easier to find the inverses of triangular matrices (and therefore solve systems of equations easier).

Comment: You are right in that $LU$ is just elimination written as a matrix factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Incomplete LU factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_LU_factorization) is one of the most effective forms or preconditioning. This procedure accelerates the convergence of sparse linear solvers, which is necessary for the rapid solution of PDE.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Precisely what I'm interested in as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want to solve $ Ax=b $ for many different right hand sides $ b $.  For example, there could be some iterative algorithm where at each iteration the right hand side changes, but the matrix $ A $ is always the same. In this case, an efficient strategy is to first factor $ A $ as $ A=LU$, for a one-time cost of $O (n^3) $. Then, at each iteration, use the pre-computed $ L $ and $ U $ factors to solve $Ax=b $ cheaply, at a cost of just $ O (n^2) $.

This is much better than paying the $ O (n^3) $ cost at each iteration.

Comment: Can you give an example of where in the real world you have such a system?

Comment: @NickThompson In algorithms for solving convex optimization problems, one often finds oneself solving multiple linear systems with the same coefficient matrix.  For example, when minimizing $f_1(x) + f_2(Ax)$ using ADMM, with $f_1,f_2$ convex, one finds oneself solving a linear system with coefficient $I + A^T A$ at each iteration.  (See slide 13-16 in Vandenberghe's 236c [notes](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/dr.pdf).)  Another example, from an interior point method, is seen on slide [18-14](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/pd.pdf) of the 236c notes.

Comment: @NickThompson Also, when solving discretized PDEs, changing loads and boundary conditions does not need to change the matrix but the right-hand side only. This makes particularly sense in PDE-constrained optimization. Another example related to your answer is preconditioning :-)